# how to provide default settings for all services started by given target in systemd

Tags: systemd

As I see /etc/systemd/system.conf has various configurations that applied to all services. Example, DefaultLimitCORE to specify the size of core-file.

A given service if needed can override these by repeating similar parameters in its configuration file. Example be below settings ensures that coredumping is enabled for the service even if it was globally disabled by default

```
[Service]
...
service--configurations
...
LimitCORE=infinity
```

As I see /etc/systemd/system.conf has various configurations that applied to all services. Example, DefaultLimitCORE to specify the size of core-file.

A given service if needed can override these by repeating similar parameters in its configuration file. Example be below settings ensures that core-dumping is enabled for the service even if it was globally disabled by default.

[Service]
...service--configurations...
LimitCORE=infinity

However, I could not find a way to override these settings at the "target" level. Example, If I define a custom target (my_target.target), how do I specify that all services that are started from this target have "limitCore" set to predefined value.